# How do I let my function return the name of any undeclared variables it accepts as an argument?

Tags: exception, sml, ml, raise

I want my function to return any undeclared variables.

e.g.

```
fun minus (x, y) = x-y;
```

If I get input "minus(1, a)", but "a" isn't declared, I want the name "a" to be raised.

How should I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "get input"? Are you implementing an interpreter?

Comment: sml doesn't use dynamically scope. It can only view variables which are bound at the position of definition.

Comment: @molbdnilo I think "get input" just means arguments here.

Comment: If you're not implementing an interpreter, SML will raise an error before your function is called. A function isn't passed names or variables, it's passed values.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is an undeclared binding, SML will not compile such a program:

```
- fun minus (x, y) = x-y;
> val minus = fn : int * int -> int
- minus (1, a);
! Toplevel input:
! minus (1, a);
!           ^
! Unbound value identifier: a
```

This is a compilation error, not a run-time exception. Getting a run-time exception because of a missing value binding is something you can achieve in dynamically typed languages, e.g. Python. As molbdnilo says, you have to implement an interpreter in SML in order to achieve dynamic behavior like this. For example:

```
datatype expr = Add of expr * expr
              | Sub of expr * expr
              | Int of int
              | Var of string

exception UnknownVar of string

fun lookup s [] = raise UnknownVar s
  | lookup s ((t,x)::vtable) = if s = t then x else lookup s vtable

fun eval vtable (Add (e1, e2)) = eval vtable e1 + eval vtable e2
  | eval vtable (Sub (e1, e2)) = eval vtable e1 - eval vtable e2
  | eval vtable (Int x) = x
  | eval vtable (Var s) = lookup s vtable
```

Running this interpreter first to produce a valid result and then an error:

```
- eval [("foo",3),("bar",2)] (Sub (Var "foo", Var "bar"));
> val it = 1 : int
- eval [("foo",3)] (Sub (Var "foo", Var "bar"));
! Uncaught exception:
! UnknownVar  "bar"
```

This is a run-time exception because of a missing variable.

Here `"bar"` is a string rather than an SML identifier.

It is only an identifier in the interpreted environment.